# Get comments from post and sort by commentmeta value

Tags: comments, comment-meta

I want to get all of the comments for a given post and return them in order by a meta_key's value desc high to low.

Doesnt look like i can do this with get_comments() like i would like to. This will give me the comments for the post but not ordered like i would like to see.

Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 2):

From the look at code [`WP_Comment_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) class, used internally by [`get_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) allows `orderby` argument to be set to `'meta_key'` string to sort by key in argument of same `meta_key` name.